# Trouble With Wiring New Switch to Replace Old Switch

Tags: lighting

I have some very old light switches that power the lights in my kitchen and dining area. There is 2 switches for each light source on each side of the kitchen/dining area, im trying to figure out where what wires go where on my new switches. Ive attached some photos that hopefully will help. Im replacing the old light switches with just basic Leviton flat style switches that toggle up or down. These - http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-Single-Pole-AC-Quiet-Switch-White-10-Pack-M32-05601-2WM/202204204

So any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: Old Light Switch]

Comment: Are the switches you linked the switches you bought?  They're only 2-way switches - the pictured ones above are 3-way.

Comment: Yes they are the exact switches I bought, Im afraid im fairly new to do it yourself electrical, and the guy at depot said theyd work fine for what I needed em for. Im guessing by your answer I need to head back to depot and get the same switches but the 3-Way version? Would you have a reference from the Home Depot website that you could give me?

Comment: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-3-Way-Switch-White-5-Pack-M42-05603-2WM/100684032

Comment: Nice clear pictures, by the way.

Comment: When changing out the switches, make sure you note and label where each wire goes. There will be one "common", which will use a different color screw then the other two. You'll also have two "travellers", which will attach to the other screw terminals. The travellers can be interchanged, so it's not important to label them uniquely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the setup now is two switches to control each light (what is known as a three-way switch) the new switches need to be the same type. A simple switch that is not a "three way switch" (they will be so labeled) won't replace those.

Return the simple switches and buy 3-way switches - then it will be easy to proceed.

Comment: Well I need the 2-way simple switches for the other switches in the house. I want to replace all the old toggle style with the newer flat style. And its only the 2 switches in the kitchen/dining area that have 2 switches for the light source.

Comment: Then you won't need the "5-pack" - They also sell singles.

Comment: Im guessing these are the ones I need to match the other ones I have - http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-3-Way-Switch-White-5-Pack-M42-05603-2WM/100684032 - also its 4 switches total and I believe the hallway light has a dual light switch setup also now that I think of it.

Comment: Oh also would the switches on the other walls that operate the light require a 3 way switch also or just the 2-way? Didn't know if they needed to be 3 or 2 way for the other ones.

Comment: Both switches (where two control one light) need to be 3-way switches (or you **can** use a dimmer that works as a 3-way switch for one of them.) If you  have 3 switches controlling one light that's a (you guessed, didn't you?) 4-way switch (less common) though it gets more complex (IIRC you use two 3-way and one 4-way, and if more switches are needed you use more 4-ways - but I'd have to look it up, that one makes my head hurt - it's also rarely seen in a normal house.)

Comment: You can put as many 4-way switches as you want between two 3-way switches. The 3-ways are called that just because they have three terminals (the common switches between the two runners), and the 4-ways have 4 terminals, and just switch the runners.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone, Im going to do a list of all the switches in the house and see how many of what kind of switches I need and away ill go. Cross your fingers I don't get zapped or burn my house down :)